# When using ray tune, value defined in config returns a non-float value

Tags: python, optimization, hyperparameters, ray, ray-tune

I'm new to use Ray Tune.
I defined my ray config as below:

```
ray_config = {
        "estimator/dropout_rate": tune.uniform(0.0, 0.3),
        "estimator/d_model": tune.choice([64]),
        "estimator/num_encoder_layers": tune.choice([3]),
        "estimator/context_length": tune.choice([4, 8, 12]),
        "trainer/batch_size": tune.choice([256]),
        "trainer/learning_rate": tune.uniform(0.0002, 0.01),
        "trainer/weight_decay": tune.uniform(1e-06, 1e-03)
    }
```

So, I tried to run my tune with this config.

```
tune.run(run_or_experiment=executor_run(hpo_params),
         metric="MAE",
         mode="max",
         num_samples=40, # number of trial models
         config=hpo_params,
         fail_fast=True)
```

But, when I see configure values in `executor_run` function, it has not a float or integer type.

```
'estimator/dropout_rate': <ray.tune.sample.Flo...d87cf7070>
```

How can I fix this? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `run_or_experiment=executor_run` (without the brackets). If you keep the brackets, the function will be executed right away. What you really want to do is to pass a reference that Ray Tune can then execute on the remote workers.

Comment: really thank you for your answer :) I solved my problem. Thank you.